# The odds that a player is in the lead after n days

Tags: probability, distributions

First off, excuse me for using layman’s terms, as I am not a stats person.

I am working on a project that has a leaderboard of 5 players. Each day we record who had the best time in the NYT crossword on our leaderboard. After 50 days, our leaderboard may look something like:

Player A: 25 wins
Player B: 15 wins
Player C: 8 wins
Player D: 2 wins
Player E: 0 wins

I want to compute the odds that a player is in first place (most wins) after N number of days, based off the current standings. This seems similar to what I know about negative binomial distributions, but more complicated, since after each day the wins/total ratio of each player changes. Even if this is ignored and the wins/total ratio of each player is taken as a constant, I don’t know how to take into account each player’s current standings.

So, I pretty much have no idea how to go about doing this and any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: One famous answer is described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points.  It does not account, though, for our sense that after so many games there is an emerging sense of relative skills of the players.  For that, many people would adopt a Bayesian approach.